# Dynamic dates in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, datetime, reporting-services

I need to make a report of all patients who had an appointment last week. This report will be added to another excel with some lookups and then put into Power BI because we don't have way of connecting our sql server.

I'm trying to reduce the amount of manual work I have to do by instead of using parameters with dates, adding a dynamic date.
I have tried using `TODAY`, `CURRENT_DATE` and they all come back with an error.

I just need it to give me data for 7 days prior to the current date
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is what the first part looks like:

```
SELECT
     PM.vwApptDetail.Patient_Last_Name
     ,PM.vwApptDetail.Patient_First_Name
     ,PM.vwApptDetail.Patient_DOB
     ,PM.vwApptDetail.Appointment_DateTime
     ,PM.vwApptDetail.Appt_Type_Desc
     ,PM.vwApptDetail.Resource_Desc
     ,PM.vwApptDetail.Status
   FROM
   PM.vwApptDetail
   WHERE
   PM.vwApptDetail.Appointment_DateTime >
```

Comment: What is the error you get when you try to use `TODAY` and `CURRENT_DATE` ?

Comment: If you are trying to use the filter in a query in SQL Server, you would use `GETDATE()` for today's date (note that it has the time so you may want to use `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`). The better way would be to add a @DATE parameter to the report and use that in the report. Then you default the date to what you want (7 days) but you'd have the option to use any date.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
WHERE Appointment_DateTime BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
```

and it seems to have worked.